# Get favicon with desired size

Tags: ios, swift, favicon

I am building a iOS Browser App. How could we get the Bookmark icons (favicons) from the given URL as Safari does (attached)? I tried `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.yourdomain.com`, but it returns only 16x16. How to get the same icons in 64x64?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following algorithm:

- Try to download `http://www.example.com/apple-touch-icon.png`. [As iOS Safari looks for this URL by convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), this is a simple trick that should sometimes work.
- Else, you need to download and parse the page (eg. `http://www.example.com`), then look for `link` markups with `rel` attribute set to `apple-touch-icon` (eg. `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">`). Finally, download the picture (eg. `http://www.example.com/icons/apple-touch-icon.png`).